# How can I extract an image and a caption dataset from a h5 file?

Tags: dataset, extract, h5py

I want to use FashionGen dataset that has 2 h5 format file for train and validation data. The h5 file's list of datasets are like this:
index
index_2
input_brand
input_category
input_composition
input_concat_description
input_department
input_description
input_gender
input_image
input_msrpUSD
input_name
input_pose
input_productID
input_season
input_subcategory

And I just need the "Input_image" and "Input_description" datasets. Would you mind help me please?

Comment: What are the `dtype` and `shape` of each dataset? What kind of Python object do you want to use for the "Input_image" and "Input_description" datasets? It's easy to create Numpy arrays with h5py.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The "input_image" dataset is """<HDF5 dataset "input_image": shape (260490, 256, 256, 3), type "|u1">""" and the "input_description" is """<HDF5 dataset "input_description": shape (260490, 1), type "|S400">""".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details depend on the dataset `dtype` and `shape` and Python objects to be created. This code will get you started. Review h5py docs for details. [h5py Quick Start Guide](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html). Note: dataset and group names are case sensitive. Be sure to verify if they are `"Input_image"` or `"input_image"`.

```
with h5py.File(filename,'r') as h5f:
    # create NumPy array from image dataset:
    image_arr = h5f['input_image'][:]
    # create NumPy array from description dataset:
    descr_arr = h5f['input_description'][:]
```

Note: if the datasets are too large to fit into memory, you can use h5py dataset objects and reference as-if they are NumPy arrays. The code is very similar. See below:

```
with h5py.File(filename,'r') as h5f:
    # create h5py object of images dataset:
    image_ds = h5f['input_image']
    # create NumPy object of description dataset:
    descr_ds = h5f['input_description']
```

Comment: You know my problem is to extract a h5 file because my lack of space. My "input_image" dataset is full of pictures and with this code, I can save a single picture. Now I want to write a for to save for emaple a hundred of these photos and also the "input_description" as txt files. And cv2 save images in BGR forms and I want them to be RGB. Can you help me please?

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('fashiongen_256_256_validation.h5', 'r')
dset = f['input_image']
data = np.array(dset[10])
file = 'test.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(file, data)

Comment: Converting from BGR to RGB is a different question. Search Stackoverflow for previous answers. If you don't find one, write a new post with appropriate image processing tags.

Comment: I've found it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now I have another problem. My "input_description" dataset is full of captions about my images. I want to save each of them as a file with .txt format for example. I did this to my image dataset with the "cv2.imwrite" method. Would you mind help me?

Comment: Loop over each row in the input_description" dataset, and write each to a separate .txt file.